# RequestHeder not getting other variables values

Tags: apache, mod-headers

I have a request that contains the header `X-Client-Cert` and I need to assign it to another header from the virtual host configuration in apache. How can I do that?

```
RewriteEngine On

RequestHeader set NewHeader "%{X-Client-Cert}e"
```

Thist solution doesn't work because X-Client-Cert is not an environment variable, however if I log the access log with

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{X-Client-Cert}i\" " ssl_f
CustomLog "logs/access_fssl.log" ssl_f
```

I can see the content of `X-Client-Cert`

Is there any form of insert the content of `X-Client-Cert` into NewHeader user defined variable?

Comment: Are you really saying you can't see the difference between "%{X-Client-Cert}e" and "%{X-Client-Cert}i" ?

Comment: "%{X-Client-Cert}e" should be an environment variable. As far as I know de "i" in "%{X-Client-Cert}i" is only used by the LogFormat to represent any http request header,

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is a possible solution that works!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Client-Cert} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=VAR:%1]

RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-Client-Cert "%{VAR}e"
```

Hope it helps somebody else!